# Page reference for information on Durin II

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, dwarves, reference

I found a note on [Tolkien Gateway](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Durin_II) that Durin II began a cooperation with the Men of the Vales of Anduin, but this simply cites *The Peoples of Middle-earth* (the section titled 'Of Dwarves and Men') and provides no page reference.

Could someone provide the page reference for this fact (along with the citation information for their copy - ISBN or what have you)? Note - the page number from the edition with the ISBN 0-395-82760-4 would be preferable, though any page number is good.

Comment: Between pages 295 and 331 of the First Edition (ISBN: 0 261 10348 2) my phone won’t let me scroll efficiently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the 2015 Harper Collins paperback edition (ISBN 978-0-261-10348-1); the page numbers in this post are from that edition.

I can't find a specific mention of Durin II, but Part Two Chapter X of *The Peoples of Middle-earth* (beginning on page 295) is called *Of Dwarves and Men*. There is a section (beginning on page 301) called *Relations of the Longbeard Dwarves and Men*. It begins by identifying Longbeard Dwarves as Durin's folk. On page 302, it describes the Longbeards began to deal with Men in Eriador.

> There dealings between Men and the Longbeards must soon have begun. For the Longbeards, though the proudest of the seven kindreds, were also the wisest and the most farseeing. Men held them in awe and were eager to learn from them; and the Longbeards were very willing to use Men for their own purposes. Thus there grew up in those regions the economy, later characteristic of the dealings of Dwarves and Men (including Hobbits); Men became the chief providers of food, as herdsmen, shepherds, and land tillers, which the Dwarves exchanged for work as builders, roadmakers, miners and the makers of things of craft from useful tools to weapons and arms and many other things of great cost and skill.
>
> <sub>*The History of Middle-earth* Volume XII, Part Two, Chapter X: *Of Dwarves and Men*</sub>
>
> <sub>Page 302 (Harper Collins 2015 paperback edition)</sub>

It goes on to say

> This system developed slowly, and it was long before the Longbeards felt any need to learn the language of their neighbours, still less to adopt names by which they could be known individually to 'outsiders'. This process began not in barter and trade, but in war; for the Longbeards had spread southward down the Vales on Anduin and had made their chief 'mansion' and stronghold in Moria;
>
> <sub>*ibid*</sub>

Although Durin II is not mentioned, this is early in the Second Age, so it is quite possible that Durin II was alive at this time (Durin I died before the end of the First Age).

Comment: This is also page 302 in my copy with ISBN 0 261 10348 2. I think this may be because the 2015 paperbacks are simply updated reprintings of the original ones. But am willing to be corrected

Comment: @Edlothiad - Other than the mass market copies of volumes 1-5, I don't think any of the HoMe volumes have ever been repaginated.